# disable caching via /proc/mtrr

Tags: linux, cpu-cache

When I'm issuing this command

```
sudo sh -c "echo \"base=0x110000 size=0xa000 type=uncachable\" >| /proc/mtrr"
```

/proc/mtrr is not changed, while I would expect it to add a new entry.

It works with this command:

```
sudo sh -c "echo \"base=0x110000 size=0x10000 type=uncachable\" >| /proc/mtrr"
```

It adds this entry:

```
reg05: base=0x000110000 (    1MB), size=   64KB, count=1: uncachable
```

So I assume that the size parameter is restricted in some ways. Are there such restrictions? Is it possible to set arbitrary memory regions to 'uncachable'?

My original (after bootup) /proc/mtrr looks like this:

```
reg00: base=0x000000000 (    0MB), size= 1024MB, count=1: write-back
reg01: base=0x040000000 ( 1024MB), size=  512MB, count=1: write-back
reg02: base=0x05f700000 ( 1527MB), size=    1MB, count=1: uncachable
reg03: base=0x05f800000 ( 1528MB), size=    8MB, count=1: uncachable
reg04: base=0x0c0000000 ( 3072MB), size=  256MB, count=1: write-combining
```

I'm using Linux 2.6.32-41-generic #89-Ubuntu SMP on a Pentium M. Reference:
http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/mtrr.txt

Background: For a timing experiment I want to disable cpu caches for the memory regions of a certain process.

Comment: I don't think this is going to do what you think it is... MTRRs change attributes on a range of *physical* memory. How that range maps to the set of pages mapped into the *virtual* address space of any particular process is up to the kernel to decide, unless you're `mmap()`-ing a fixed address range for some reason...

Comment: Thanks for the hint, twalberg, I wasn't aware of that. So I think I'll have to write a kernel module to controll the physical address(es) of the proces' memory. But I guess it is still best to use the /proc/mtrr interface to set the MTRRs?

Comment: `/proc/mtrr` is probably the easiest way to modify the MTRRs, yes. But make sure you really understand the ramifications of changes you make - that's an easy road to system instability or worse. There are probably better ways to accomplish what you're wanting to, but you haven't provided a lot of detail about what that is...

Comment: My final goal is to run a program where the code (without libraries) will not be cached. I allready disabled the CPU caches completely (setting the CR0 register) but found out that the libraries need to be cached for the experiment. My current understanding is that it has to be done using the MTRRs (be it with /proc/mtrr or not), but this may of course be incorrect.

Comment: In that case, you'll probably need to make sure the code segment gets locked in memory (so it doesn't get relocated to other physical pages), figure out what physical ranges that virtual range is mapped to, and change the attributes on those physical ranges. Not easy to do from user-space; easier to do in the kernel, but probably still not a cake walk...